Can not click() on Selenium
Code on the IDE
I am trying to click a checkbox and I am not able to do it.
try {
    WebElement primaryParticipant = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"searchable-list-input-primaryParticipantSearchable\"]"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    WebElement other = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[5]/mat-checkbox[@class=\"mat-checkbox chp-ds pt-75 mat-primary ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid\"]")));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", other);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", primaryParticipant); //Scroll into the Additional Participants Section
    captureImage();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement participantText = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c14-7\"]/textarea")));
    participantText.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    participantText.sendKeys("Automation Test");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    captureImage();
} catch (Exception e) {
    captureImage();
    throw new AssertionError("Could not select Other on the checkbox or write on it.", e);
}

Right now I am trying to do the click() with Javascript because I found the error related to
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted:

So I am trying with Javascript. When I try to do the click with Javascript the element is not being clicked and I am getting an error of the next variable participantText that it is not visible. This is because the checkbox of Other was not clicked and the TextArea is not visible.
How can I click on Other?

Can you share a link to the page? There's no way we're going to be able to figure out the click intercepted without a lot more info and access to the page would likely solve the issue. You've got a lot of sleeps mixed with waits that I'm confused by. You shouldn't need both and you should always prefer waits and avoid sleeps whenever possible.
